# DisableViewPicker in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

our CRM was update to this version:

```
2021 release wave 1 enabled
Server version: 9.2.21054.00135
Client version: 1.4.2741-2105.4
Organization name: ********
Session ID: ********
Time: 6/22/2021 3:47:19 PM
```

And after this update 1 script stoped working because it tries to disable view picker.

```
function setDefaultView(viewId, fiedlId) {
Xrm.Page.getControl(fiedlId).setDefaultView(viewId);

**parent.document.getElementById(fiedlId).attributes.disableviewpicker.value = "1";**
}
```

I tried this options I found online but it seems none of them are supported

```
function setDefaultView(viewId, fiedlId) {
        Xrm.Page.getControl(fiedlId).setDefaultView(viewId);
        
        var partnerField = Xrm.Page.getControl(fiedlId);
        
        partnerField.SetParameter("disableViewPicker", "1");
}
```

Also when i try to debug this no longer returns information

[image]

Is there a new way to turn on/off the view picker with JS?
I cant find any recent information about this subject.

UPDATE:

What i need is, if that source campaign is selected, to disable view picker in that lookup field.

[image]

Thanks in advance
Miguel Vale

Comment: you maybe aware - document.getElementById is unsupported in Dynamics world :)

Comment: it was working for at least for 2 years with this line parent.document.getElementById(fiedlId).attributes.disableviewpicker.value = "1" :(

Comment: that was working doesn't mean it was supported. Please add some screenshots and details on what you need to accomplish, maybe there is an alternative

Comment: uhm, if you need to remove the option to select a different view just when there is a specific campaign, I would probably create a second lookup with that limited view that is visible only when that campaign is selected and after copy the value to the original lookup. It's a bit cumbersome but should work and it's supported.